# How do i get the video frames from webrtc localstream to python

Tags: javascript, python, django, image-processing, webrtc

I am trying to create a video call application like google meet or zoom
with object detection in python flask or django.

the app works this way:

- the user can join a channel for the video call
- the camera  starts on the client machine
- each frame will be sent to the python to do some image processing(object detection)
- then the frame will be pass to my object detection model which is yolov5.

I found out that I can't use opencv right away since it only works locally.
so I tried to search for something I can use and I found webrtc,
I searched for some examples on how to use it and found this code here

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>DEMO</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container-fluid">
        <video id="localVideo" playsinline autoplay muted></video>
        <video id="remoteVideo" playsinline autoplay></video>

        <div class="box">
            <button id="startButton">Start</button>
            <button id="callButton">Call</button>
            <button id="hangupButton">Hang Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.css

```
body{
    background-color: #121212;
}
button {
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    width: 83px;
}

button#hangupButton {
    margin: 0;
}

video {
    --width: 45%;
    width: var(--width);
    height: calc(var(--width) * 0.75);
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

video#localVideo {
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

div.box {
    margin: 1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    button {
        width: 83px;
        margin: 0 11px 10px 0;
    }

    video {
        height: 90px;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        width: calc(50% - 7px);
    }
    video#localVideo {
        margin: 0 10px 20px 0;
    }

}
```

main.js

```
'use strict';

const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
const callButton = document.getElementById('callButton');
const hangupButton = document.getElementById('hangupButton');
callButton.disabled = true;
hangupButton.disabled = true;
startButton.addEventListener('click', start);
callButton.addEventListener('click', call);
hangupButton.addEventListener('click', hangup);

let startTime;
const localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');

localVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  console.log(`Local video videoWidth: ${this.videoWidth}px,  videoHeight: ${this.videoHeight}px`);
});

remoteVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  console.log(`Remote video videoWidth: ${this.videoWidth}px,  videoHeight: ${this.videoHeight}px`);
});

remoteVideo.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  console.log(`Remote video size changed to ${remoteVideo.videoWidth}x${remoteVideo.videoHeight} - Time since pageload ${performance.now().toFixed(0)}ms`);
  // We'll use the first onsize callback as an indication that video has started
  // playing out.
  if (startTime) {
    const elapsedTime = window.performance.now() - startTime;
    console.log('Setup time: ' + elapsedTime.toFixed(3) + 'ms');
    startTime = null;
  }
});

let localStream;
let pc1;
let pc2;
const offerOptions = {
  offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
  offerToReceiveVideo: 1
};

function getName(pc) {
  return (pc === pc1) ? 'pc1' : 'pc2';
}

function getOtherPc(pc) {
  return (pc === pc1) ? pc2 : pc1;
}

async function start() {
  console.log('Requesting local stream');
  startButton.disabled = true;
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true});
    console.log('Received local stream');
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    localStream = stream;
    callButton.disabled = false;
  } catch (e) {
    alert(`getUserMedia() error: ${e.name}`);
  }
}

async function call() {
  callButton.disabled = true;
  hangupButton.disabled = false;
  console.log('Starting call');
  startTime = window.performance.now();
  const videoTracks = localStream.getVideoTracks();
  const audioTracks = localStream.getAudioTracks();
  if (videoTracks.length > 0) {
    console.log(`Using video device: ${videoTracks[0].label}`);
  }
  if (audioTracks.length > 0) {
    console.log(`Using audio device: ${audioTracks[0].label}`);
  }
  const configuration = {};
  console.log('RTCPeerConnection configuration:', configuration);
  pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
  console.log('Created local peer connection object pc1');
  pc1.addEventListener('icecandidate', e => onIceCandidate(pc1, e));
  pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
  console.log('Created remote peer connection object pc2');
  pc2.addEventListener('icecandidate', e => onIceCandidate(pc2, e));
  pc1.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', e => onIceStateChange(pc1, e));
  pc2.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', e => onIceStateChange(pc2, e));
  pc2.addEventListener('track', gotRemoteStream);

  localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc1.addTrack(track, localStream));
  console.log('Added local stream to pc1');

  try {
    console.log('pc1 createOffer start');
    const offer = await pc1.createOffer(offerOptions);
    await onCreateOfferSuccess(offer);
  } catch (e) {
    onCreateSessionDescriptionError(e);
  }
}

function onCreateSessionDescriptionError(error) {
  console.log(`Failed to create session description: ${error.toString()}`);
}

async function onCreateOfferSuccess(desc) {
  console.log(`Offer from pc1\n${desc.sdp}`);
  console.log('pc1 setLocalDescription start');
  try {
    await pc1.setLocalDescription(desc);
    onSetLocalSuccess(pc1);
  } catch (e) {
    onSetSessionDescriptionError();
  }

  console.log('pc2 setRemoteDescription start');
  try {
    await pc2.setRemoteDescription(desc);
    onSetRemoteSuccess(pc2);
  } catch (e) {
    onSetSessionDescriptionError();
  }

  console.log('pc2 createAnswer start');
  // Since the 'remote' side has no media stream we need
  // to pass in the right constraints in order for it to
  // accept the incoming offer of audio and video.
  try {
    const answer = await pc2.createAnswer();
    await onCreateAnswerSuccess(answer);
  } catch (e) {
    onCreateSessionDescriptionError(e);
  }
}

function onSetLocalSuccess(pc) {
  console.log(`${getName(pc)} setLocalDescription complete`);
}

function onSetRemoteSuccess(pc) {
  console.log(`${getName(pc)} setRemoteDescription complete`);
}

function onSetSessionDescriptionError(error) {
  console.log(`Failed to set session description: ${error.toString()}`);
}

function gotRemoteStream(e) {
  if (remoteVideo.srcObject !== e.streams[0]) {
    remoteVideo.srcObject = e.streams[0];
    console.log('pc2 received remote stream');
  }
}

async function onCreateAnswerSuccess(desc) {
  console.log(`Answer from pc2:\n${desc.sdp}`);
  console.log('pc2 setLocalDescription start');
  try {
    await pc2.setLocalDescription(desc);
    onSetLocalSuccess(pc2);
  } catch (e) {
    onSetSessionDescriptionError(e);
  }
  console.log('pc1 setRemoteDescription start');
  try {
    await pc1.setRemoteDescription(desc);
    onSetRemoteSuccess(pc1);
  } catch (e) {
    onSetSessionDescriptionError(e);
  }
}

async function onIceCandidate(pc, event) {
  try {
    await (getOtherPc(pc).addIceCandidate(event.candidate));
    onAddIceCandidateSuccess(pc);
  } catch (e) {
    onAddIceCandidateError(pc, e);
  }
  console.log(`${getName(pc)} ICE candidate:\n${event.candidate ? event.candidate.candidate : '(null)'}`);
}

function onAddIceCandidateSuccess(pc) {
  console.log(`${getName(pc)} addIceCandidate success`);
}

function onAddIceCandidateError(pc, error) {
  console.log(`${getName(pc)} failed to add ICE Candidate: ${error.toString()}`);
}

function onIceStateChange(pc, event) {
  if (pc) {
    console.log(`${getName(pc)} ICE state: ${pc.iceConnectionState}`);
    console.log('ICE state change event: ', event);
  }
}

function hangup() {
  console.log('Ending call');
  pc1.close();
  pc2.close();
  pc1 = null;
  pc2 = null;
  hangupButton.disabled = true;
  callButton.disabled = false;
}
```

This sample shows how to setup a connection between two peers in different tabs using RTCPeerConnection and Broadcast Channel. I would like do more in the future like adding rooms where users can join but this good for now.

1. My question is how do I send each frame from my webrtc localstream to the python server side to do a real-time object detection?
2. Is my project even possible?

I have find some approach on how to this but I don't really get how they work

First is the aiortc:

https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/tree/main/examples/server

The second one is this:

https://webrtchacks.com/webrtc-cv-tensorflow/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02Bmt7tksvM&t=288s

I have limited knowledge on webrtc and computer vision so if you guys have any idea on how to implement it or any other solutions you could offer, please comment since i really need help, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you suggesting is definitely possible. You can capture user's camera stream in browser, send it to your python backend using webrtc and do any processing you want. Conferencing can be implemented on top of it as well. But keep in mind that it would probably be a long journey.

A good starting point is [aiortc server example](https://github.com/jlaine/aiortc/tree/master/examples/server). It shows how to capture a video stream from browser, send it to your opencv backend via webrtc, process and send back to be displayed to user.

To add conferencing you will need to maintain webrtc connections for each user and send all active media streams to each one.

To build a media server like this you will need a good understandment of webrtc. As a brief tour see [WebRTC in 100 Seconds // Build a Video Chat app from Scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmR9IMUD_CY). But i also highly recommend [webrtc for the curious](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/) as a deeper dive, it's probably the best material about webrtc out there.

Also, from what i've read it's actually possible to run opencv in browser environment. The answer is [webassbembly](https://webassembly.org/) - a technology that allows compiling a code in many different languages to a binary instructions browsers can understand. Check out the [opencv npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv-wasm).

If client-side video processing is an option it might save you resources on the server-side and reduce its complexity.
You might actually take an opensource conferencing service like [peercalls](https://peercalls.com) and add video processing on a client-side without significant changes on backend if it suits your needs.